# Getting an url's miniature on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, image, url

I'm making an iOS app which relies a lot on web urls added via a Safari extension. It works, no problem with that, but… well, it's ugly. I'd like to use the miniature of the url like the new Messages rich links in iOS 10 or Facebook Messenger.

The problem is: I did a little research,  but can't find anything about that on iOS. I thought about parsing the HTML for an image, but it will probably be too random from a website to another, right?

If someone know the answer or something that would lead me to it, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: Most websites have a favicon.ico or favicon.png, have you tried using that?

Comment: Render the HTML code in a virtual web view and create an image from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I chose to use OpenGraph. A lot of websites implement it, not all, but it's a good start.

I use [that wrapper](https://github.com/satoshi-takano/OpenGraph) found on Github, but I also found [URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/URLEmbeddedView) if you prefer something ready to use.

Answer (score -1):

Look for a `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">` in the head tag of a the webpage. A lot of websites have this. If you can't find an icon, then I would try finding an `<img src ...>`, which is similar to the solution you suggest.

If that doesn't work, I might actually start looking for dominant colours, but that would be a bit more work.